# Asyncio in a for loop

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio

So I am trying to do something like this,

```
for job in jobs:
    input = some_io_task(job)
    output_list.append(process(input))

return output_list
```

I want the loop to continue as the some_io_task function is being executed, and come back to the that particular iteration and then append to the output list, the order in which the append takes place does not matter, and I am trying to do this using asyncio in python. I am new to this and would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is the function an async function? If so `create_task` is what you're looking for. I only worry about the fact that you're trying to put it together without much understanding in asyncio, and it'll be quite complicated. Have you read some asyncio tutorials?

Comment: Could you put the crate_task modification for the above code please? I have read a few tutorials and watched videos, but a few more guides wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 1):

Per your request, here is an example considering `some_io_task` returns an awaitable:

```
import asyncio

async def some_io_task(job):
    ...

async def stuff(jobs):
    # Create all coroutines for the jobs
    tasks = map(some_io_task, jobs)
    # Schedule all coroutines, returning each as they're ready
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = await task
        output_list.append(process(result))
    return output_list
```

It is extremely specific to your case. Keep in mind I'm missing some information about `some_io_task` but I believe this should explain it well enough.

Comment: I think this is basically reinventing ``asyncio.gather``. Might be easier to use it directly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi nope, it isn't. `process` happens while the jobs in the background are still running <3. Are you following me btw? :P

Comment: Ah, right you are; I didn't notice the ``process`` wrapper in the question. And just following the same tags.